# Как сделать одноразовый ввод в телеграм боте aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Нашел вот такой метод

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
async def answer_to_messages(message: types.Message):
    print(message.text)
    await message.answer("Получил твое сообщение")
```

Но он "бесконечный", то есть он сработает как только пользователь введет сообщение он сразу вызовется. Можно сделать так чтоб работал один раз?

Comment: Ты хочешь,чтобы бот всего олин раз в жизни отправил это сообщение,т.е. если человек до этого уже отправлял такое сообщение , то ему бот отвечать не будет?

Comment: Запиши где-то факт срабатывания хендлера и делай проверку

Comment: Еще как вариант смотри в сторону FSM