# "Бесконечный" хендлер aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, telegram

Только изучаю aiogram и в качестве практики решил написать "онлайн бар"

Бот запрашивает напиток а потом выводит его

Проблема в том что если пользователь один раз вызовет /order то бот будет считывать сообщения вечно. А надо только один раз после вызова команды

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

bot = Bot(token="token")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def inserting_text_cars(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Бар")


@dp.message_handler(commands=['order'])
async def inserting_text_cars(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Что будете пить?")

    @dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
    async def answer_to_messages(message: types.Message):
        await message.reply(f"Вы будете пить {message.text}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Вы там что задания школьные делаете или что? [Почти такой же вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1485328/Как-сделать-одноразовый-ввод-в-телеграм-боте-aiogram)

Comment: О и в дополнение [Почему не стоит запихивать хендлеры внутрь других хендлеров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1478675/Почему-не-стоит-запихивать-хендлеры-внутрь-других-хендлеров)

Comment: Он наверное с табами ошибся ,поэтому так и получается ,насчет школьного задания - бот для телеграмма на питоне.Бот,телеграмм,питон - крутые слова,вот все и начали,это же здорово:)

Comment: @АнтонСибгатулин скорее всего это не ошибка с табуляцией, они очень часто так делают. Извращение какое-то. Меня смутила сама проблема, что нужно сделать `одноразовый`  хендлер так еще и в один день